# Parrallelogram with css

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get the same effect as the background on the Locnville website: http://locnville.com (the slanted squares or parallelograms, whatever.) I can get a parallelogram with css as there are thousands examples but I can not get the same effect. Can anyone help me with this?

My CSS:

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Please show what your previous attempts at doing this were. You can post some code of what you've tried so far, or perhaps link to some sites you've found. Try doing some research before asking your question here.

Comment: Is that more like what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/SeHtM/

Comment: @Tim - Yes, exactly. But if I put text in it, it is also tilted. Can I overcome this? Or should I make this a background and something over it which is basically n plain square?

Comment: One option would be to use absolute positioning and position another div over it for text. Another option would be to make a div for the text with a triangle above and a triangle below(looks like a parallelogram then). It should be possible without images.

Comment: For help with the triangle approach, look here: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you're looking for is the slanting from top left to bottom right (or vice versa) so the top edge is at an angle?

<del>You need to rotate your box, and remember in doing so the height and width values are essentially swapped...</del>

If you need your content in it to not be skewed...

```
#parallelogram {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;

}

#parallelogram:before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) skew(0,5deg);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) skew(0,5deg);
       -o-transform: translateY(-50%) skew(0,5deg);
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  bottom:-200%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Playing with padding and positioning will give you the shape you want (as well as the skew), taking in to account advice from Tim in comments.

Comment: rotattion is not necessary. See my fiddle in the comment to the question.

Comment: Stick it down as an answer ;)

Comment: Feel free to steal any of my comments for your write up. I am only in a browsing mood. Too tired to contribute for real at the moment.

Comment: Fair enough, was working on the text issue anyway :) 

It's important to note that this is probably the preferable way to code a stylistic element like this, since it's not content so shouldn't really be executed through additional DIV use!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two separate divs, with a top padding on the second div element, as well as a background-image with no repeat and top position property pointing to your slanted square image (which should match the first divs background color). Fairly simple CSS, although I would have taken it a step further and used a :before or :after element and no image.